# How to mark a new message/new notification as `unread`?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I want to mark some of my chat messages and/or notifications as unread after I read it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Marking messages as unread after reading them**

Go to your inbox, click on a message, click on "Actions" and then "Mark as unread"

[image]

**Marking friend notifications as unread**

There is no direct way to do this but until you have responded to a friend request (either accepted or declined), a count will be shown (like in the image below):

[image]

**Marking notifications as unread**

Again, I don't see a direct way of doing this. One work around would be to go to Settings > Notification Settings and turn on email notifications. You can mark the email as unread until you wish to do so!

[image]

Hope this helps!